# Modern Capistrano Deprec recipes for Xapian, MongoDB, etc

Tags: ruby, mongodb, capistrano, xapian

I am looking for some modern Capistrano 2.x / Deprec recipes for setting up toosl ike MongoDB, Xapian and Xapian-fu, and other tools (Redis, Memcache/d, etc)

Anyone know if Deprec is still active enough to have some recipes for some of these modern tools

Thanks

Charles

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into using [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) to manage the tool/system configuration and continue to use Capistrano for app deployment.

There are modules to integrate Capistrano with either Chef or Puppet, eg:

- [capistrano-chef](https://github.com/cramerdev/capistrano-chef)
- [capistrano-puppet](https://github.com/garethr/capistrano-puppet)

The Chef community is growing quickly but Puppet has been around for longer.  The community contributed Puppet recipes tend to have broader O/S support, but Chef is catching up.

Either could be a great choice but discussing the merits of each for this question would lead to extended debate :).

A few perspectives:

- [Puppet vs Chef - Fight!](http://devopsanywhere.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/puppet-vs-chef-fight.html)
- [Why We Chose Chef](http://www.nathenharvey.com/blog/2011/11/21/why-we-chose-chef-over-puppet-at-customink)

[deprec.org](http://deprec.org/) and the [deprec-users discussion group](http://deprec.org/) both seem rather dormant at the moment.